# Link to my flags

Tags: support, flags

On Stack Overflow, on my profile page I can access the list of my flags, 
[image: screen shot]

but not here, on Android Enthusiasts:

[image: screen shot]

I know that on  SO the link appears after at least one helpful flag, but I have manually composed the [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/668) to check that and I have two helpful flags now.

Is this option completely missing on Android Enthusiasts, it's a bug for me or I don't know where to look for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, it looks like you're using the "collapsed" view of your profile here at the moment. There should be a link next to your name that says `more info`. Click on that to expand it, which will reveal additional profile information (including your flag count).

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I have completely missed that small green link and I was always wondering why you have a different profile page style on AE :D